# Is it guaranteed that global variables are always initialized to 0 with c99?

Tags: c, variables, initialization, c99

From [6.7.8.10](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in the C99 standard:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules.

Is a global variable of any type (array, structure, bitfield) always defined as a `static storage`?

Comment: Yes, as far as they are stored into `bss` section.

Comment: Oh ! That's the point. How can I ensure it is in the `bss` section?

Comment: "global variable" is not a term used by the C Standard.  "object with static storage duration" is.  If you are still unclear, perhaps describe exactly what you mean by "global variable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that global variables are always initialized to 0 with c99?

Yes and no

```
static void *g_v_ptr;  // initialized to a null pointer
```

C99 details a *value*, but not its representation.  "it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer" implies that the pointer has value of a *null pointer*.  This may or may not be `NULL`.  This may or may not be `0`.  A compiler may have many bit patterns that correspond to a *null pointer*.  In any case, the `g_v_ptr == NULL` is true as well as `g_v_ptr == 0`, but the pointer may have a different bit representation than `0`.  Certainly a pattern of all zero bits is usually easy to implement and certainly the most likely implementation.  Yet the spec is just squishy enough to allow for some non-zero bit pattern to be used.

A similar case can be made for floating point numbers.

In any case (IAC), the initialized value will *equate* to 0.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (5.1.2 Execution environments)

> 1 Tw o execution environments are deﬁned: freestanding and hosted. In
>   both cases, program startup occurs when a designated C function is
>   called by the execution environment. **All objects with static storage
>   duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before
>   program startup.** The manner and timing of such initialization are
>   otherwise unspeciﬁed. Program termination returns control to the
>   execution environment.

and (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 3 An object whose identiﬁer is declared without the storage-class
>   speciﬁer _Thread_local, and either **with external or internal linkage
>   or with the storage-class speciﬁer static, has static storage
>   duration.** Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its
>   stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's guaranteed (at least since C89). "Global variables" (either with internal or external linkage) have *static storage duration*. Any object with static storage is guaranteed to be zero initialized according to C99, 6.7.8 Initialization.

[C99 draft, 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.4p3):

> 3 An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal
> linkage, or with the storage-class specifier static has static storage
> duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its
> stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

[6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.2) describes the linkage of identifiers, particularly in relation to "global" variables:

> 3 If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage- class specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.22)
>
> 4 For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,23) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Ignoring the case which [could lead to undefined behaviour](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.2p7), all file scope identifiers with either internal or external linkage and they all have static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as they are stored into `bss` section.

Your linker script define it and (mainly) default linker scripts do that. 
While you can manually store data in different section manually, global scoped variable too.

BTW is the startup code that is responsible of zero the section. If you are working with non standard platforms or your startup code is made by you, you must ensure that.

Comment: Is this really part of the C standard? I could not find `bss` in my C99 copy. While `bss` definitely is a frequently used name, it does not seem to be officially specified.

Comment: @Gerhardh not a Standard Lawyer, but it is the way that grant the standard. The Vlad's answer pointed out the standard requirement.

Comment: The section in which a global variable is stored has nothing to do whether or not for the user it will appear to be initialized to `0`. The only thing that counts are the guarantees that the C standard gives, here. How a particular platform achieves that, hast not to be the business of a C programmer.

Comment: @JensGustedt A C programmer, especially on embedded tiny platform, should take care of it, seriously. Section matters here, a lot. What if you define a global variable within a specific section that startup code will not zero? What if, on an embedded platform, a `const` global variable is stored not inited into onChip flash?

Comment: @LPs, what if the compiler & toolchain that is used does not name that section `bss`? That's rather implementation defined and not part of the C standard, I would say.

Comment: @Gerhardh It isn't a compiler/toolchain matter. It is a linker matter. You can choose to put what you want where you want, but startup code looks only to bss section. I Think that OP question is, Ok the standard says that, but what is granted in real world?

Comment: @LPs, yes, but all of this is much too specialized, and gives no general answer to the question that was asked. This should be a comment to one of the other answers, not more.

Comment: @LPs: The compiler and the linker must agree on the same usage of section names. This makes it a compiler and toolchain issue. What would it be worth if the compiler creates sections `.code` & `.data` while the linker expects `text` & `bss`? If the standard does not mention any sections it all comes down to checking your toolchain spec. Therefore just throwing `bss` into the game is not that much helpful.

Comment: @Gerhardh And what if The compiler and linker expect the same, but I choose to store some global scoped variable/struct into a specific section? I know that the standard does not mention anything about section, but is how usually the real word apply the standard. I saw many questions like this with OP expecting that all globals are zeroed even if linker scripts are proprietary.

Comment: @LPs: In general, platforms provide for the initialization of certain designated sections; if you force a variable into any other section, you become responsible for its placement and any initialization it may require.  This is allowable under the Standard, since implementations are allowed to do anything they like with any program that uses implementation-reserved identifiers or `#pragma` directives, provided only that they document their behavior.